# Executing multiple procs in select statement to return row count

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

Here is what I am trying to do, get the number of rows that a stored proc returns (plus a column name that it has in the proc)
**Obviously this is Pseudo-Code**

```
SELECT
(select col_name, Count(*) FROM stored_proc1)
(select col_name, Count(*) FROM stored_proc2)
(select col_name, Count(*) FROM stored_proc3)
```

To return 2 columns as such

```
col_name  |  row_count
----------------------
myCol1        3
myCol2        6
myCol3        8
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the col_name part will be but you might wish to look at [@@ROWCOUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx)

So something like

```
DECLARE @R1 INT
EXEC SP1
SET @R1 = @@ROWCOUNT
DECLARE @R2 INT
EXEC SP2
SET @R2 = @@ROWCOUNT

SELECT 'SP1' SP_Number, @R1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SP2' SP_Number, @R2
```

Comment: How would I attach a column name to the count column?

Comment: which column would you want to "attach"?

Comment: a column that is in every one of these SP.  with the row count.  Also need to label the column that contains the @R1 (counts)